# Folder/file protection with web.config

Tags: .net, web-config

I'm trying to prevent download of .doc files in a folder `[root]/content/downloads/documents` using the Web.config.  I have read posts on here and other sites; added a new web.config to the folder`[root]/content/downloads/documents` and put the following inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
    <allow roles="Members"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

I was expecting this to deny access to the .doc file if I entered its URL but I am still able to download the file.

When a user logs in, they will log in as a "Member". This will allow them to download anything in the above folder.  If they're NOT logged in, no download.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11973992/34397

Comment: IIS 7. I saw this article but it didn't work. I have found some code I used in the past using the `<location path="..."/>` property but this is not protecting the documents as expected.